# Setting Class Object Array Property

Tags: arrays, excel, class, object, vba

I'm trying to set a property of an object which is part of a class object array, for excel in VBA.

The code looks like this:

```
Dim myClass(5) as class1
Dim i as integer

For i = 0 to 5
    set myClass(i) = New class
    myClass(i).myProperty = "SomeValue"
Next i
```

Class code is simply:

```
Private pmyProperty as string

Public Property Let myProperty(s as string)
    pmyProperty = s
End Property
Public Property Get myProperty() as string
    myProperty = pmyProperty
End Property
```

However when I run this, I get a compile error "expected: list separator." This hits on the myClass(i).myProperty = "SomeValue" line.

How do I set the value of a property of an class object that is part of an array?

Any help would be great!

---

So the actual code is as follows...

Module code:

```
Public Sub main_sb_BillingApp()


    Dim intCountComplete As Integer
    Dim intLastRow As Integer
    Dim Line() As clsLine
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer

    intCountComplete = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(WS_NAME).Columns(COL_W_COMPLETE), "Yes")
    intLastRow = Sheets(WS_NAME).Cells(LAST_ROW, COL_W_COMPLETE).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    ReDim Line(intCountComplete - 1)

    For i = ROW_W_HEADER + 1 To intLastRow

        If Sheets(WS_NAME).Cells(i, COL_W_COMPLETE) = "Yes" Then

            Set Line(x) = New clsLine
            Line(x).Row = i
            x = x + 1

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Class code:

```
Private pDate As Date
Private pUJN As String
Private pDesc As String
Private pCharge As Currency
Private pCost As Currency
Private pMargin As Double
Private pComplete As Boolean
Private pRow As Integer

Public Property Let Row(i As Integer)
    pRow = i
    Update
End Property
Public Property Get Row() As Integer
    Row = pRow
End Property

Private Sub Update()

    With Sheets(WS_NAME)

        pDate = .Cells(pRow, COL_W_DATE)
        pUJN = .Cells(pRow, COL_W_UJN)
        pDesc = .Cells(pRow, COL_W_DESC)
        pCharge = .Cells(pRow, COL_W_CHARGE)
        pCost = .Cells(pRow, COL_W_COST)
        pMargin = .Cells(pRow, COL_W_MARGIN)

        If .Cells(pRow, COL_W_COMPLETE) = "Yes" Then
            pComplete = True
        Else
            pComplete = False
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it VB.NET *or* vba *or* vbscript?

Comment: show relevant `class` code

Comment: The code I'm using is VBA for excel.

Comment: Added the class code.

Comment: What line is the error on?  Also, do not call your class `class`.  Call it `class1` or something else.

Comment: The code you posted runs just fine. Is that the *actual code that gives the compile error*?

Comment: This is a common error when you haven't properly closed a string - i.e. you're missing a `"`. Sometimes this is because you actually have `“` instead of `"` - which can be caused by copying/pasting your code from another source, rather than directly typing it into the VBE.

Comment: I've added my actual code - the snippet before was a simplified version where the error was occuring.

Comment: Your actual code *also* compiles cleanly for me.

Comment: Yeah - just added in the line that caused the error (removed it previously to test a few things)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Line` is a VBA reserved keyword, so you're confusing the compiler.  Change the name of your object array and it works just fine:

```
Dim lineArray() As clsLine
'...

        Set lineArray(x) = New clsLine
        lineArray(x).Row = i
```

Comment: Changed the name and worked perfectly! Thanks for your help!